# High performance desktop virtulization / multithreading on the guest with linux 64 bit host

Tags: virtualbox, vmware-workstation, esxi, linux-kvm

For over 3 years I have been trying to get similar guest performance in 64 bit windows as I have on my i7 870 at work in the tasks I do at work. My requirements are pretty taxing. I need fast CPU, fast disk, 6+ GB guest ram and accelerated opengl all that I need guest SMP with greater than 4 guest cores so that my source code building (>3 million lines of c++ code) and 3D medical image processing has a acceptable level of performance.

I have over these years tried xen, EXSi, vmware player, vwmare server, VirtualBox, kvm. All of these have one issue (performance problem and/or instability) or another. I just upgraded my CPU to a 6 core / 12 threaded i7 970 however that seems to have not helped the situation. vmware player does not support more than 4 guest cores (I want to assign my guest 8 of the 12 threads). VirtualBox 4.1.X supports any number of cores but it does not appear to faster with more than 4 guest cores and it also still randomly locks up the guest. kvm also supports more cores but has very slow video (even with the qxl driver). I did not try xen or ESXi since I want fast host video and do not want to have to use 2 graphics cards to get that.

I am beginning to think what I want is just not possible today and I would be better served with converting the machine to a 64 bit windows machine and dual booting or putting the less taxing linux system as guest on windows virtulization instead.

Does anyone have a good working solution for similar requirements or am I just wasting my time and money with virtulization on problem that can not be solved in 2011?

Comment: What is your **actual question**?

Comment: Anyone have a working solution or am I just wasting my time and money with virtulization on problem that can not be solved in 2011?

Comment: With those requirements, why are you running a VM at all? Also, your question isn't clear & likey to be closed. Please edit with what is it that you're asking for

Comment: I want to run linux as the host since the host is part of a linux network containg my htpc which is linux based and has 10TB storage.

Comment: IMHO that doesn't justify running a Linux host, and as you've tried probably every software solution there is, I'm afraid that's as far as you'll get.

Comment: I have not tried vmware-workstation recently. vmware-player was working okay but it did not have the multithreaded CPU performance (took much longer to compile, process ..) as my 4 core / 8 threaded i7 870 at work and the vm guest has a advantage of having a higher clock speed of 3.2GHz and an SSD versus the desktop system with a 7200 RPM hard drive. I also have not tried making windows the host and linux the guest or even dual booting.

Comment: Thanks, I am now trying to use a few different options with windows as the host OS. However testing will take weeks since I do not have a lot of free time.